# Get queue name from within MDB

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, message-driven-bean

Is it possible to infer the name of the bound queue or listener port from within an MDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The best you can do is declare an env-entry with a description that indicates to the deployer that it should have the same value set as the queue or listener port name.